# Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Code explanation:  I am returning specific HTML file when user visit specific url:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./funkcionalnosti-streznika.html', function(err1, html1) {
    fs.readFile('./posebnosti.html', function(err2, html2) {
        if (err1 || err2) {
            throw new Error();
        }

        http.createServer(function(req, res) {
            if (req.url == '/funkcionalnosti-streznika') {
                res.write(html1);
                res.end();
            }
            if (req.url == '/posebnosti') {
                res.write(html2)
                res.end();
            } else {
                res.write('random');
                res.end();
            }
        }).listen(8080)
    })
});
```

on terminal I've got this error when I visit localhost:8080/funkcionalnosti-streznika:

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:637:17)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:629:15)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/*filelocation*/:19:21)
    at Server.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:784:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:692:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
```

I think there is I problem when I close the response too early. How should I change this to be async?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["write after end" error in a server made with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140841/write-after-end-error-in-a-server-made-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 35):

You have already realized what the problem is. Let's take a look at this code:

```
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        if (req.url == '/funkcionalnosti-streznika') {
            res.write(html1);
            res.end();
        }
        if (req.url == '/posebnosti') {
            res.write(html2)
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.write('random');
            res.end();
        }
    }).listen(8080)
```

Let's suppose that `req.url` is '`/funkcionalnosti-streznika'`. What happens? It enters the first if, writes `html1` and ends `res`. Then it is checked against `'/posebnosti'`, but it's different, because the first `if` was true. This means that the `else` branch will be executed, so `res.write('random');` is called, but `res` was already closed in the first `if`. Suggestion:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/funkcionalnosti-streznika') {
        res.write(html1);
        res.end();
    }
    else if (req.url == '/posebnosti') {
        res.write(html2)
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.write('random');
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(8080)
```

Comment: I was taking a look at the documentation and I still don't understand: does the res.end() method only signals that the message is complete or does it actually ends the request? is there any other way of using it in the above example as you would with a "return" at the end of a if condition to ignore the other cases?

Comment: @MarcusCastanho kindly read https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback basically you end writing into the writable. In the code above you could remove all the `res.end()` lines and put them after the if-else if-else blocks, since it is called in all cases. `return` assigns a value to a function and stops its execution. res.end signifies the end of the writing. You could do `return res.end();` if that helps.

Answer (score 12):

Just write return after every if, this will stop further execution of the code.

Comment: That was the only answer the saved me, after many tries. Thank you, harshit.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of multiple "if" condition use "if else" or just return  every "if" condition.

```js
// ...
if (req.url == '/funkcionalnosti-streznika') {
  res.write(html1);
} else if (req.url == '/posebnosti') {
  res.write(html2);
} else {
  res.write('random');
}
res.end();
// ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can check using inside your API using `if (res.writableEnded) return;` to see if your middleware have already wrote to the response stream (it used to be `response.finished` but got deprecated)

Comment: it seems response.finished is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*if (req.url == '/funkcionalnosti-streznika') {
return res.end('case-1');
}
if (req.url == '/posebnosti') {
return res.end('case-2');
}
res.end('other case');
*/
```

It help me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).